# ListView is not clickable, all widgets in rows are TextView

Tags: android, list, listview, textview, row

I have a simple row model and a ListView in a Fragment; the ListView gets properly populated, with all the correct dimensions, colors, etc. Problem is, clicking on a row fires no event.

The code in my fragment is:

```
MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, strings);
mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("LIST", "Selected item # " + position);
    }
});
```

The fragment layout (a piece of it) is:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/m_list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true">
</ListView>
```

The row layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_surname"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/surname"
        style="@style/ListStyleXLarge"/>

    <!-- 4 more TextView just as the first one -->
</LinearLayout>
```

The style is simply:

```
    <style name="ListStyleXLarge">
    <item name="android:textSize">
        @dimen/text_size_large
    </item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">
        bold
    </item>
    <item name="android:textColor">
        @color/list_item_text_color
    </item>
</style>
```

What can fix this problem? I have already tried to set the

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focuseable="false"
android:focuseableInTouchMode="false"
```

to all of the TextViews, but nothing so far.

Comment: Please check below link more helpful to you http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: I did everything as in every tutorial I've read so far, and it should be working. In fact, populating the list with android's default simple rows it all works. That's why I think the problem is in the row layout.

Comment: please try custom listview  example http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

Comment: Have you tried to use ListFragment? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: Tried that. The problem appears to be in the row layout, because I really can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MyAdapter class:

In the getView method use:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("LIST", "Selected item # " + position);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your list_item xml put android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in the LinearLayout or RelativeLayout you have.