# Click is not working on the Listitem Listview android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, listactivity

I implemented the android `listview` with the `ListActivity`. Here I have the problem that when i click on the list item no action is performed when the flash color is also not coming that is the orange color. So do you have any idea about this kindly answer to my question.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

}
```

I put this code also into the Main ListActivity.

Comment: Do you have any button or ImageButton in your List?

Comment: @android Selva: Yes I have... Its a problem?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The first thing what you have to note here is, whenever there are Clickable elements like Buttons or `ImageButtons` present in your `ListView` element, they take the control of click events. And so your `ListView` won't get the chance to accept the click event.

What  you simply have to do is, set the `focusable` attribute to false for the `Button` or `ImageButton` you have in your ListView. But still they will work without any problem and also your ListView's `onListItemClick` will also work.

Try this,

```
        <Button  android:id="@+id/textsize_increaser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back_button"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text=" A + "/>
```

Here I have added this `android:focusable="false"` and it works fine. try it.

Comment: You should add also `clickable=false` if you listen to item click only

Comment: Please help me. I have been stuck on this for the last 7 hours now, and it is such a simple question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108940/why-cant-i-remove-an-item/35109304#35109304

Comment: For me, `imageButton.setFocusable(false)` and `imageButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false)` **in adapter** helped. In XML there was no effect!

Comment: you saved my @ss, thank you from the future, stranger! :)

Answer (score 12):

Have you set the choice mode of ListView to SINGLE :

```
     listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

And if you have any clickable imageview or textview or button in the list item, then make them not focusable (in your Adapter class):

```
        yourButton.setFocusable(false);
        yourButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Comment: Please help me. I have been stuck on this for the last 7 hours now, and it is such a simple question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108940/why-cant-i-remove-an-item/35109304#35109304

Answer (score 4):

Are you using custom Adapter? and inflating layout with button or any view that eats away the list list view focus as child, then it won't work obviously. make sure to set

```
    android:focusable="false"
```

to such view in xml file. hope this works for you.

Comment: Please help me. I have been stuck on this for the last 7 hours now, and it is such a simple question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108940/why-cant-i-remove-an-item/35109304#35109304

Answer (score 4):

Set this in your listactivity java file

```
listview1.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a parameter meant for that to prevent children views from getting focus, just add the following in the parent layout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

As the documentation explains:

> The ViewGroup will block its descendants from receiving focus.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse suggested me to add `textIsSelectable="true"` to my TextViews in the layout xml which was used for list view.

Well, if you want to click the items in the list then you should not add those tags.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you are

1. Not using Scroll View with List View
2. Not using Scroll View in your row item layout for List View

If Scroll View is present at any of above place remove it

Answer (score 0):

refer to this post for a solution:

[Click is not working on the Listitem Listview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610023/click-is-not-working-on-the-listitem-listview-android/17345235#17345235)

```
View v = parent.getChildAt(position);
parent.requestChildFocus(v,view);
v.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable."Some drawable for clicked row"));

int count = parent.getChildCount();
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
   if(i!=position)
   {
     v = parent.getChildAt(i);
     v.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable."some drawable for not clicked row));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                    long id) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), exm.get(pos).getDefinition(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listItemButton.setFocusable(false);
listItemButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Set the above in your **adapter**. It's not working in **XML**