# Item selection not working after adding Button

Tags: android, listview, button

I am developing an android application using a `ListView`as a main interface. Each item in the `List` contains `TextView` and `Button`. When the `Button` is visible the item selection does not work and when the button is not visible the item selection work without problem. This problem is not reproduced if I change the button by an `ImageView`.

Is there a solution to make the item selection work when the Button is visible?

Comment: can you add some code so we can see what is going on?

Comment: Please show us the list view and also the listener/handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly we can't set the click option for both `List` item and the `Button`. So we have to use the custom adapter.

Try this example : http://code.google.com/p/codemobiles/source/browse/CustomListViewDemo/

[Click is not working on the Listitem Listview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610023/click-is-not-working-on-the-listitem-listview-android)