# ToggleButton checked in wrong ListView rows

Tags: android

I have a ListView with toggleButton in each row. When the toggleButton of a row is checked, I noticed that when I scroll down the ListView, every first out of 10 rows will also be checked.

How to ensure that only the selected row's toggleButton is checked? Here is my ArrayAdapter:

```
class AppListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {

        private List<ApplicationInfo> applicationInfoList;
        private Context context;
        private PackageManager packageManager;

        public AppListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                              List<ApplicationInfo> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);

            this.context = context;
            this.applicationInfoList = objects;
            packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ((null != applicationInfoList) ?
                    applicationInfoList.size() : 0);
        }

        @Override
        public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
            return ((null != applicationInfoList) ?
                    applicationInfoList.get(position) : null);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if(null == view) {
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_application, null);
            }

            final ApplicationInfo data = applicationInfoList.get(position);

            if(null != data) {
                CardView rowLayout = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_layout);
                TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_app_name);
                ImageView iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_app_icon);
                ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.row_toggle_lock);

                appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
                iconView.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
                checkToggleStatus(toggleButton, rowLayout, data);
            }

            return view;
        }

        private void setToggleButton(ToggleButton toggleLock, ApplicationInfo data) {
            if(toggleLock.isChecked()) {
                toggleLock.setChecked(false);
                applicationLocked.remove(data);
            } else if(!toggleLock.isChecked()) {
                toggleLock.setChecked(true);
                applicationLocked.add(data);
            }
        }

        // This method updates the lock status of each application and
        // pop-up dialog that allows users to set start and end date to lock the application.
        private void checkToggleStatus(final ToggleButton toggleLock,
                                       final CardView rowLayout, final ApplicationInfo data) {

            rowLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    appDatabase.setDefaultLockStatus(appDatabase, data.packageName);
                    Animation rotate360 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.shake);
                    toggleLock.startAnimation(rotate360);
                    setToggleButton(toggleLock, data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView item is reuse.

Here is an example:
[checkable-listview](https://github.com/yantze/checkablelist)

Same with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910822/list-item-layout-containing-a-checkbox-doesnt-work-as-expected/43220937)