# How to find the position of item in listview

Tags: android

I have created a Custom listView where i put some text and image but when i clicked in list view their is no response.I have created a custom Listview.
if any one known then please tell me.
my code is here

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final List<pdf> pdfList;

    //the listview
    final ListView listView;

        //initializing objects
      pdfList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        //adding some values to our list
      pdfList.add(new pdf("Book1", "First Year"));
     pdfList.add(new pdf( "Book2", "First Year"));
        //creating the adapter
        ListAdptot adapter = new ListAdptot(this, R.layout.customlistview, pdfList);

        //attaching adapter to the listview
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > adapter, View view, int position, long arg){

                                       if(position==0)
                                       {
                                           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       }

                                      else if(position==1)
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any clickable views inside your list item, then it will consume click event of your ListView item click.

Set `android:focusable="false"` on your `Button` or `ImageButton` if you have any.

Reference [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624769/6891563)

Answer (score 2):

Get list item positon click as below

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > adapter, View view, int position, long arg){

                                  String value = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                                }
                            }
);
```