# ListView row with EditText, clickability, and context menu -- how to put it together?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a `ListActivity`-based activity that uses a context menu for the items. After adding an `EditText` to the row of a `ListView`, the context menu stopped working, and also the item does not react on a click. It seems that it is blocked somehow by the focus of the `EditText`. I can enter the `EditText` value, but I cannot get the earlier context menu, and I cannot start another activity via clicking the item.

I have possibly found the [related comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8955441/1346705%C2%A7) that says:

> Android doesn't allow to select list items that have focusable elements (buttons). Modify the button's xml attribute to:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

> It should still be clickable, just won't gain focus...

... so I did the same for the `EditText` (I am not sure if the button case can be generalized for the `EditText`). Anyway, the item is clickable again, the context menu appears... However, the `EditText` part of the text stopped working now. (Actually, I did not implement the reaction to the `EditText` -- the keyboard simply does not appear.)

Is it possible to have the clickability of the list item and also make the `EditText` work the expected way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this would help you but it is a post I've found when I was trying to use a ListView with buttons inside.

[ListView Tips & Tricks #4: Add Several Clickable Areas](http://www.cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not have time to implement the ideas from the Cyril Mottier's article, but it seems to be the right source of information. Thanks a lot.