# ListFragment as ActionBar Tab. TextView elements not clickable. Tried many different solutions

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, clickable

I have a ListFragment which is a Tab (one of many) in my ActionBar. The problem is that none of the list elements is clickable (onListItemClick() is never called). The element consist of two TextViews.
I have tried many different things including:

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
android:textIsSelectable="true" 
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
android:clickable="false"
```

ListFragment layout:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Row item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_emergency_number_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_emergency_number"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Do you have any clue whats wrong with it?

Comment: why android:clickable="false" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955270/listview-items-are-not-clickable-why It was mentioned as one of the solution. 
I've tried android:clickable="true" also

Comment: By not clickable you mean that when you touch the textview nothing happen ?

Comment: Nothing happen no matter whether I touch TextView or list row

Comment: If it where me i would use regular Fragment and use a listview in it with an adapter... Could you post your fragment layout, and the class using it ?

Comment: I've used regular Fragment. The result is the same.

Comment: This is so trivial, look at your code more closely, do some log. And maybe post more code, we can't just guess.