# Android ListView Item not clickable

Tags: android, listview, cursor, customization

i've a problem with my ListView: the (customized) items are only clickable on the divider. I've looking a few hours for a solution but nothing worked for me.

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" dosen't work correctly. Setting focusable=„false“ on each childitem dosen't work too. does anyone know a solution for this issue?

ItemLayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/elremFontMedium"
            android:id="@+id/detailNoticeText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This ist my ListView

```
<ListView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/detailNoticeListView"/>
```

As Adapter I used a CursorAdapter

```
public class NoticeAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public NoticeAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_detail_notice_item, parent, false);

        return retView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView textViewNotice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailNoticeText);
        textViewNotice.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NOTICE_TABLE_COLUMN_TEXT)));
    }
}
```

The onItemClick is in my Fragmant

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        switch(adapterView.getId()) {
            case R.id.detailNoticeListView:
                Cursor cursor = mNoticeAdapter.getCursor();
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);

                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailNoticeText);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(NoticeDialog.EDIT_TEXT_ID, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                bundle.putString(NoticeDialog.EDIT_TEXT, textView.getText().toString());

                NoticeDialog noticeDialog = new NoticeDialog();
                noticeDialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
                noticeDialog.setArguments(bundle);
                noticeDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"noticeDialog");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: write more code from your class that using this list view

Comment: Where are you setting the onItemClickListener?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView items are not clickable. why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955270/listview-items-are-not-clickable-why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.
The reason was that I modify the TextView Style like this.

```
<style name="elremFontMedium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
     <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
     <item name="android:textIsSelectable">true</item>
</style>
```

The problem was `<item name="android:textIsSelectable">true</item>`.
So I removed this attribute and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:clickable="true"` to the `LinearLayout` of `ItemLayout.xml`. Also where is your `onItemClickListener` ?

Comment: Add clickable=true dosen't work too. The listener is located in my fragment. I've added in my question.