# Why In custom listview is not working with setOnItemClickListner?

Tags: java, android, list, listview

I have a list view with two text views and one edit text in each row `listView.setOnItemClickListener()` is not working.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Log.e("position", String.valueOf(position));
           }
       });
```

`Log.e("position", String.valueOf(position));` not displaying on Logcat

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question so we can help you.

Comment: Not idea without code

Comment: please show your the code

Answer (score 1):

If you items are coming with Model then create an object of your model in your setOnItemCLickListner like below code and then get data from model according to position.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        ActivityModel booking = movieList.get(position);
                        String id = booking.getActivityId();
                        Toast.makeText(this, id , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
```

In your XML add below property in listview.

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the focus is on the `EditText`. In XML add this to your editText view `android:focusable="false"`

Further read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8955441/5954246

Answer (score 1):

This is because the editText is consuming your focus and thus no click is getting registered.

When I set `android:focusable="false"` for EditText then onItemClick on the ListView item is working, but EditText doesn't get cursor when I click inside.

If I'll set `android:focusable="true"` for EditText, then EditText is focusable, but onItemClick for the ListView doesn't work when I click on it.

So modify your adapter in this way:

```
    public class AdapterListCards extends CursorAdapter implements View.OnTouchListener {
 public AdapterListCards(Context context) {
    super(context, null, true);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (view instanceof EditText) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) view;
        editText.setFocusable(true);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    } else {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.edtCode.setFocusable(false);
        holder.edtCode.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    }
    return false;
 }

 private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    EditText edtCode;
}

 @Override
 public View newView(final Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    holder.edtCode = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pass);
    holder.edtCode.setOnTouchListener(this);
    convertView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    return convertView;
 }

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    if (cur!=null) holder.txtName.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("name")));
 }
}
```